# Eclipselink jpa - sql query result mapping to java object

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to return a typed list from getResultList() but I am having issues with mapping my sql result list to a typed list. It keeps returning a list of generic objects. This is my current code:

```
EntityManager em = this.emPool.createEntityManager();
TypedQuery<Runtime> query = Runner.getRuntime(em);
List<Runtime> runtimeList = query.getResultList();
```

Also, in Runner class I have this:

```
    public static TypedQuery<Runtime> getRuntime(EntityManager em) {
        return em.createNamedQuery(COUNT_RUNTIMES_SQL_EXPRESSION, Runtime.class);
    }
```

And here is the query:

```
SELECT u.runner_id as runnerId, COUNT(u.times) FROM RUNNER u"
        + " WHERE u.age = :60 GROUP by u.runner_id
```

Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: the query I am running is a report query -> a simple group by and count

Comment: You mention having issues but you don't really tell us what they are..

Comment: the issue is that the result is returned as a list of generic objects, not as the expected type

Comment: Why not take the time to update your question with some actual information, like posting the query, the `Runtime` class, and maybe what SQL is executed in the datastore?

Comment: Do you have an entity mapped for the Runner table or are you forced to use a Native SQL query?  The answer below applies to JPQL/Criteria queries, but you will need to use an SqlResultSetMapping otherwise to tell JPA how to put your SQL results into a java object - see https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.5/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html and https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-constructor-result-mappings/ for using it with a constructor

Answer (score 0):

You need to use constructor expression in select clause. For example,

```
SELECT new com.example.Runtime(u.runner_id as runnerId, COUNT(u.times)) FROM RUNNER u"
        + " WHERE u.age = :60 GROUP by u.runner_id
```

Define the corresponding constructor in the class Runtime.

If using Criteria API, CriteriaBuilder.construt(...) should be used. Tested with [Cmobilecom JPA](http://cmobilecom.com) for the criteria API.

Disclaimer: I am a developer of Cmobilecom JPA (for java and android)